# Locust workers set to "missing" as soon as job starts

Tags: python, kubernetes, locust

I'm running locust `locust==2.8.6` on python 3.10. I run it on kubernetes via AWS EKS. I run it distributed and am trying to set up 1 master and 5 workers.

The master pod starts with command:

```
command: ["locust"]
        args: ["-f","$filename","--headless","--users=$clients","--spawn-rate=$hatch-rate","--run-time=$run-time","--only-summary","--master","--expect-workers=$num_slaves"]
```

and the workers start with command:

```
command: ["locust"]
        args: ["-f","$filename","--worker","--master-host=locust-master$task_id"]
```

Indeed, on a worker pod, I can run `telnet locust-master1 5557` and confirm communication. (In that case, $task_id=1)

I see logs in the master pod as below:

```
[2022-04-27 22:53:16,969] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/root: Waiting for workers to be ready, 0 of 5 connected
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,109] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-slave1-tt7n5_fec1320a406b42319f3088bd9a7c181c' reported as ready. Currently 1 clients ready to swarm.
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,147] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-slave1-qv7kt_011dbeb9f15d452f935c5643fb463632' reported as ready. Currently 2 clients ready to swarm.
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,261] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-slave1-ks5wb_356fcf54ac2644e4badc684e3846520c' reported as ready. Currently 3 clients ready to swarm.
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,354] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-slave1-cbkbd_2c90cedde5224e1e9cf47bbb543b9097' reported as ready. Currently 4 clients ready to swarm.
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,364] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Client 'locust-slave1-xfvsz_196bba3928c5491e896acd411798d48d' reported as ready. Currently 5 clients ready to swarm.
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,970] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.main: Run time limit set to 5400 seconds
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,971] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 2.8.6
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,971] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Sending spawn jobs of 50 users at 0.50 spawn rate to 5 ready clients
[2022-04-27 22:53:17,977] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust_submit_judgments: Locust Startup: job_id: 1434194
[2022-04-27 22:53:18,376] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Worker locust-slave1-cbkbd_2c90cedde5224e1e9cf47bbb543b9097 failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing.
[2022-04-27 22:53:20,384] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Worker locust-slave1-qv7kt_011dbeb9f15d452f935c5643fb463632 failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing.
[2022-04-27 22:53:20,385] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Worker locust-slave1-ks5wb_356fcf54ac2644e4badc684e3846520c failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing.
[2022-04-27 22:53:22,391] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Worker locust-slave1-tt7n5_fec1320a406b42319f3088bd9a7c181c failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing.
[2022-04-27 22:53:22,391] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: Worker locust-slave1-xfvsz_196bba3928c5491e896acd411798d48d failed to send heartbeat, setting state to missing.
[2022-04-27 22:53:22,392] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust.runners: The last worker went missing, stopping test.
[2022-04-27 22:53:22,392] locust-master1--1-z2lr8/INFO/locust_submit_judgments: Locust Teardown: sending query messages to Results DB
```

So I do see the workers register themselves, but as soon as the test starts, the master pod says the workers fail to send heartbeats and sets them to missing. If I run the master pod without `--headless`, that means I can open the web UI and manually start the job. I see the same problem: when I start the job manually, the same heartbeat messages appear.

On the worker pods, I see my debug startup logs and nothing that indicates an issue.

I cannot find a guide online on how to set up distributed locust (except for when it was called locustio and in version 0.x) and things have changed a lot since then.

What needs to be set here? I am not sure which code to include without including many lines of setup code. I am trying to test against postgres so I'm thinking of following https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html but in all the examples they are wrapping attributes which is a departure from the code I've inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked CPU utilization on the master/worker node? We had a similar case when VM's were having 100% CPU consumption and worker simply didn't had the possibility to send heartbeat since CPU was overwhelmed with the requests that Locust wanted to make.

The separate mechanism for processing heartbeats might not work properly under this condition and as consequence nodes will disconnect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

Depends on implementation of postgress test, you might need to make sure you are use correctly gevent. See [this](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html) comment from the documentation :

> It is important that the protocol libraries you use can be monkey-patched by gevent.

In my case I have used a Snowflake custom testing class, suffering from the same issue because the requests were blocking. Adding [Monkey patching](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching) fixed the issue .